# Named pipe, read fail with bad file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I'm beginning with pipes under Linux and I have a problem with my code.
I wanted to test sending an integer through the fifo so I code a small program to test it.

First I open the read only descriptor and then the write only one as precised in the documentation.
I send the number to the pipe and close the write descriptor.

However, when I'm trying to read from the pipe, it says that I have a bad file descriptor, I don't understand why it's not working because as the descriptor is the good one and is oppened with good option (O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK).

Here is my code :

```
void main(void)
{
    int modePipeWrite, modePipeRead;

    if(mkfifo("test.fifo", 0777) == -1)
    {
        perror("mkfifo");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(modePipeRead = open("test.fifo", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK) == -1)
    {
        perror("openRead");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(modePipeWrite = open("test.fifo", O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK) == -1)
    {
        perror("openWrite");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    int n = 0;

    if(write(modePipeWrite, &n, sizeof(n)) == -1)
    {
        perror("write");
    }
    printf("Send value: %d\n", n);

    close(modePipeWrite);


    int mode;

    while(1)
    {
        if(read(modePipeRead, &mode, sizeof(mode)) == -1)
        {
            perror("read");
        }
        printf("Received value: %d\n", getpid(), mode);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

And the output :

```
./a.out
Send value: 0

read: Bad file descriptor
Received value: -1877110288

read: Bad file descriptor
Received value: -1877110288

read: Bad file descriptor
Received value: -1877110288
```

I don't understand what could be wrong here. If someone have some advices I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: I cannot immediately explain the exact nature of the problem, but pipes are a mechanism for *inter-process* communication.  They are neither intended nor well-suited for a single process to communicate with itself.

Comment: I guess you shouldn't be closing the pipe until you're done reading from it.

Comment: Maybe, @mustaccio, but he opens the read and write ends as separate files, so that's not at all clear.  I suspect it's a combination of some or all of (1) opening both ends in non-blocking mode, (2) in the same process, *and* (3) closing the write end before the read.

Comment: maybe remove the`O_NONBLOCK` ?

Comment: Do also note that from a user program perspective, there are two distinct kinds of pipes in Linux: *named* pipes, a.k.a. FIFOs, and anonymous pipes created via the `pipe()` function.  The latter are by far the more commonly used.

Comment: If I don't use the O_NONBLOCK the openning of the read descriptor is never passed.
In my application, I need this process to create the pipe and then to poll the value in it, this value can then be modified by another process to change the behaviour of this process.
It will basically be a deamon which watch the value in the pipe every x second. This value represent its working mode.
The value 0 is written because it's its default configuration mode when the deamon is launched.

Comment: Note this comment from the man pae: *However, it has to be open at both ends simultaneously before you can proceed to do any input or output operations on it.*  Also note *Opening a FIFO for reading normally blocks until some other process opens the same FIFO for writing, and vice versa.*. So it's really not intended to communicate within a single process.

Comment: So if I understand well I should create the pipe and write the default value from the parent process and then fork this process, demonize it and at this moment I should be able to poll from the pipe without openning the write descriptor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a couple of issues, which you would've found if you compiled it with all warnings enabled. If you use gcc, the following options are nice/mandatory:
     -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic

One issue is that you don't assign the return value of open() to the file descriptors. You need to add braces around the assignment, or move it out of the if-statements.

Here's a working example, using a thread to read:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <pthread.h>

static void *reader(void *arg)
{   
    int fd, val;

    if ((fd = open("test.fifo", O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
        perror("openRead");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (read(fd, &val, sizeof val) == -1)
        perror("read");
    else
        printf("Received value: %d\n", val);

    close(fd);
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{   
    int modePipeWrite, modePipeRead;
    pthread_t readerid;


    if (mkfifo("test.fifo", 0777) == -1) {
        perror("mkfifo");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    pthread_create(&readerid, NULL, reader, NULL);
    sleep(1);

    if ((modePipeWrite = open("test.fifo", O_WRONLY)) == -1) {
        perror("openWrite");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int n = 1234;

    if (write(modePipeWrite, &n, sizeof n) == -1)
        perror("write");
    else
        printf("Sent value: %d\n", n);

    sleep(1);
    close(modePipeWrite);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't realize it was that simple... Thanks a lot for your help, it's working as I was expecting.
Just a question, How can I write an integer from the shell into the pipe? Because when I'm doing "cat 4 > test.fifo" The read value change to 2612 but when I'm doing this from another program it's ok.

Comment: 4 is just an ASCII value. You either need to convert it to a four byte integer or -- better -- read text in the program and convert it to an integer. (Maybe fdopen() and fscanf() can be useful? )

Comment: I though it was possible to tell to the shell to intepret 4 as a integer value. Whatever this is absolutely not related with the topic, I'll dig around later.
Thanks again ;)